# Infinite loop and number of slides on mobile not working with Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel-2, sliders

I've created a slider using Owl Slider v2.2.1. I have two issues.

1. I need it to have a infinite loop, i'm setting loop:true but it doesn't seem to work.
2. I need there to be a minimum of two slides. I've set this to 2 but it only shows two down to 480px then it shows 1, is there a way to change the breakpoint?

.

```
$('.m19-owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    center: true,
    loop: true,
    items: 4,
    responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 2,
        },
        600: {
            items: 3,           
        },
        1000: {
            items: 4,
        }
    }
})
```